# Recuperar valores JSON em Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho que criar um JSON a partir de um primeiro JSON.

```
{  
        "event":"comprou",
        "timestamp":"2016-09-22T13:57:31.2311892-03:00",
        "revenue":250,
        "custom_data":[  
            {  
                "key":"store_name",
                "value":"Patio Savassi"
            },
            {  
                "key":"transaction_id",
                "value":"3029384"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Nesse que tenho que criar, a estrutura tem que ser desse tipo:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2016-10-02T11:37:31.2300892-03:00",
  "revenue": 120.0,
  "transaction_id": "3409340",
  "store_name": "Loja do Pedro"
}
```

Como eu posso acessar o `transaction_id` e o `store_name`?

Comment: Use `JSON.parse` para gerar um objeto a partir do texto, acesse os valores com a forma `objeto.atributo` montando um novo objeto da forma que você precisa e, finalmente, use `JSON.stringify` para converter o objeto em texto. Quer tentar?

Comment: No custom_data sempre chegam dois itens ou isso é dinâmico? pode ser que cheguem N objetos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Primeira Forma:

Você pode criar uma função customizada para formatar os dados da maneira como desejar. No exemplo abaixo, a função `formatJSON` cria um objeto com duas propriedades iniciais (`timestamp` e `revenue`). Após isso, um laço é feito sobre o *array* `custom_data`, adicionando os demais valores ao objeto.

```js
const first = {  
  event: 'comprou',
  timestamp: '2016-09-22T13:57:31.2311892-03:00',
  revenue: 250,
  custom_data: [  
    {  
        key: 'store_name',
        value: 'Patio Savassi'
    },
    {  
        key: 'transaction_id',
        value: '3029384'
    }
  ]
};

function formatJSON (data) {
  const object = {
    timestamp: data.timestamp,
    revenue: data.revenue
  };

  for (const customData of data.custom_data) {
    object[customData.key] = customData.value;
  }

  return object;
}

console.log(formatJSON(first));
```

Note que para encurtar o código, podemos rescrever a função `formatJSON`, usando um novo recurso do JavaScript, chamado [*destructuring*](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment):

```
function formatJSON ({ timestamp, revenue, custom_data: data }) {
  const object = { timestamp, revenue };

  for (const { key, value } of data) {
    object[key] = value;
  }

  return object;
}
```

## Segunda forma:

Se você simplesmente quiser acessar as propriedades `store_name` e `transaction_id`, pode fazer assim:

```js
const oldObject = {  
  event: 'comprou',
  timestamp: '2016-09-22T13:57:31.2311892-03:00',
  revenue: 250,
  custom_data: [  
    {  
        key: 'store_name',
        value: 'Patio Savassi'
    },
    {  
        key: 'transaction_id',
        value: '3029384'
    }
  ]
};

const newObject = {
  timestamp: oldObject.timestamp,
  revenue: oldObject.revenue,
  store_name: oldObject.custom_data[0].value,
  transaction_id: oldObject.custom_data[1].value
};

console.log(newObject);
```

Como `custom_data` é um `array`, podemos acessar um elemento específico usando o seu índice, através da notação `array[index]`. Para saber mais, leia [essa documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) sobre `array`s na MDN.

## Adendo:

Lembre-se que para converter uma `string` para JSON (`object` no JavaScript), utilize:

```
JSON.parse('{ "hello": "world" }');
```

E para transformar um JSON (objeto) em `string`, utilize:

```
JSON.stringify({ hello: 'world' });
```

#### Referência:

- [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse);
- [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: Funcionou aqui, muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada. Qualquer coisa, só falar. :)